# Greasemonkey communication with server that requires windows-1250 encoding

Tags: javascript, http, character-encoding, xmlhttprequest, greasemonkey

I'm developing a **greasemonkey** plugin, which is supposed to send a form in background using POST (GM_xmlhttpRequest) on an application not under my control. That application is written in PHP and seems to expect all its input in windows-1250 encoding. What I need to do is to take all the form fields as they are, edit just one of them and resubmit. Some of the fields use accented characters and are limited in length.

Not a problem in theory - I iterate over all form fields, use the encodeURIComponent function on the values and concatenate everything to a post request body. HOWEVER. The encodeURIComponent function always encodes characters according to UTF-8, which leads to all sorts of problems. Because PHP doesn't seem to recode my request to windows-1250 properly, it misinterprets multibyte strings and comes to the conclusion that the resubmitted values are longer than the allowed 40 characters and dies on me. Or the script just dies silently without giving me any sort of useful feedback.

I have tested this by looking at the POST body firefox is sending when I submit the form in a browser window and then resending the same data to the server using xhr. Which worked. For example the string:

`Zajišťujeme profesionální modelky`

Looks as follows, when encoded by encodeURIComponent:

`Zaji%C5%A1%C5%A5ujeme%20profesion%C3%A1ln%C3%AD%20modelky`

Same thing using urlencode in PHP (source text in windows-1250) or Firefox:

`Zaji%9A%9Dujeme+profesion%E1ln%ED+modelky`

Apparently, I need to encode the post body as if it were in windows-1250 or somehow make the server accept utf-8 (which I doubt is possible). I tried all kinds of other function like escape or encodeURI, but the output is not much different - all seem to output in utf-8.

Is there any way out of this?

Comment: Myself, I actually think the only way is to do the recoding on the server, urlencode it there and send back to the client script to send to the external website. I'd love to be proved wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to get Firefox to encode a URL is to set it as the href of a link. The property (NOT attribute) will always read back as an absolute link urlencoded in the page's encoding.

For a GET request you would simply set the href as `http://server/cgi?var=value` and read back the encoded form. For a POST request you would have to take the extra step to separate the data (you can't use `?var=value` on its own because the link reads back as an absolute link).

Answer (score 1):

Let the browser encode the form.  Put it in a hidden iframe and call submit() on it.

Comment: If I do it that way, will I be able to get notified when the submission finishes?

Comment: The page that is returned when you submit would need to notify you.